# How to create sharepoint 2013 alert on task item few days before due date? No sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow, sharepoint-online

I have created a SharePoint 2013 task list. I need to send alert email to the assigned to person few days (say 3 days) before the due date. what is the better way to address this issue without using SharePoint designer workflow? I don't think there is any oob solution for this. I have SharePoint 2013 on prem environment.

Comment: Wondering why you wouldn't use SharePOint Designer Workflow...

Comment: We are planning to migrating to SharePoint 2016 online  so I don't think SharePoint designer workflow won't be a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do it manually(like on button click), go with JSOM / REST API(preferred).
Using SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail you can send custom email to target audience.

if you want to do it automatically then you have to use CSOM managed code, using this you can write timer job that will perform desired task.

first option is less hectic and easily doable because it's java script, but it needs user interaction like clicking of button which will check to whom alert email should be send.

In Second option you have to write console application which automatically get executed by window timer job.

Comment: we are planning to migrate the SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016 online, what would be the better approach to address this situation automatically? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hopefully you will get some idea, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/remote-timer-jobs-sharepoint-add-in

Comment: Azure webjobs would be better approach in this case.